# How to join page and pagecontent in mediawiki database?

Tags: database, join, mediawiki

How can I join the tables page and pagecontent in the mediawiki database? In the Scheme http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/MediaWiki_database_schema_1-17_%28r82044%29.png it seems like the Joining has to go over the table recentchanges but this table is empty in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If by "pagecontent" you mean the `text` table, the most straightforward way is to go through the `archive` or `revisions` tables (depending on whether the revision in question is deleted or not). `recentchanges` is emptied after a certain (configurable, IIRC) period of time, and is there to support watchlists, Recent Changes, and other like features.